# How to configure Managed Navigation to display the current site and items below the current site

Tags: 2013, navigation, metadata

When configuring the Current Navigation the only Managed Navigation option is

> Managed Navigation: The navigation items will be represented using a Managed Metadata term set.

When I select this option the left hand navigation shows the entire Managed Navigation hierarchy for the site.

How can I configure this so that the left hand navigation displays only the current site and items below the current site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible using the OOTB Managed navigation. The only workarounds I can figure is using different Term Sets for different sub webs, or to write your own navigation control

Comment: Creating additional Term Sets for the navigation items on the different sites is not ideal but it does work.  Thanks for the suggestion.